# How can we check the type if we have tcmUri using Core Services?

Tags: core-service

If I've tcmUri say(tcm:31-2-1) how can I know the nature of it. Whether it is Component,Page,Schema,Folder etc. Do we have anything in core services by which we can check>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use this TcmUri class: https://gist.github.com/quirijnslings/d9ff8a421f9087b4b24f8b8942de6675.

You can use it like this:

```
var uri = new TcmUri("tcm:0-23-1");
var itemType = uri.ItemTypeId;
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me !!!

Answer (score 4):

You can just look at it and see.

Tcm Uri is constructed of publication id, item id, and item type. In your case:

- 0 is the publication id where your item is.
- 23 is the item id
- 1 is item type which is publication type.

So, you can just get that last number and find it in the core service `ItemType` enum:

[image]

**Also, make note that components are specific, meaning that they don't need to have 16 added, so you need to check that one also.**
**My case, just split that string into sections. Check for the last section that is item type and compare**